# Проблема с заполнением массива через цикл

Tags: c, массивы, циклы

Я запускаю цикл. Он должен пройти 3 круга так как al = 0, 0 + 1, 1+1 и тут стоп. Но он проходит очень странным образом либо 4 либо 3 раза, сейчас объясню. Первый круг, должно вывестись в printf("Times: %d\n", al ); :  Times: 0, но ничего не выводится а лишь запрашивается х в scanf_s. Второй круг выводится уже Times: 0 , которое должно вывестись в первом круге, и опять запрашивается х. Теперь уже третий круг выводится Times: 1 и так далее... И теперь почему-то проходит четвертый круг который выводит Times:2 и запрашивает значение x которое улетает в никуда.
**Полный вывод програмы:**

```
1
1
Times: 0
2
Times: 1
2
Times: 2
First: 1 | Second: 1, | Third: 2
```

**Код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int al = 0, x;
    int array[3];
    while (al<=2) {
        scanf_s("%d\n", &x);
        array[al] = x;
        printf("Times: %d\n", al );
        al++;
    }
    printf("First: %d | Second: %d, | Third: %d \n", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `scanf_s("%d", &x);` - что получится?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решится если в `scanf_s` убрать `\n`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int al = 0, x;
    int array[3];
    while (al<=2) {
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        array[al] = x;
        printf("Times: %d\n", al );
        al++;
    }
    printf("First: %d | Second: %d, | Third: %d \n", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Директива `"\n"` также как и директива `" "` говорит функции `scanf_s` считать все имеющиеся во входном потоке пробельные символы. Символ новой строки `\n` также считается пробельным символом.

Вот как работает ваш цикл.

*Нулевая итерация* (`al == 0`). Вы вводите в консоль символ `1` и нажимаете Enter. Во входной поток добавляются символы: `1\n`. Функция `scanf_s` считывает символ `1` и помещает число `1` в переменную `x`, затем считывает символ новой строки и... ожидает дальнейшего ввода. Ведь функция должна считать **все** имеющиеся пробельные символы во входном потоке, и пока вы не введёте ещё что-нибудь, она не сможет понять, считаны ли все имеющиеся пробельные символы или нет.
Вы повторно вводите в консоль последовательность символов `1\n`. Функция `scanf_s` видит, что следующий символ во входном потоке не является пробельным и прекращает свою работу.

Итак, к концу нулевой итерации имеем следующий расклад:
`array[0] == x == 1`,
`printf` выводит `Times: 0`,
во входном потоке находится последовательность символов `1\n`.

*Первая итерация* (`al == 1`). Так как во входном потоке уже имеются символы `1\n`, то функция `scanf_s` успешно считывает символ `1` из входного потока и помещает число `1` в переменную `x`. Затем считывает символ новой строки `\n` и... ожидает дальнейшего ввода, чтобы понять все ли пробельные символы она считала. Вы вводите символы `2\n`. Функция видит, что следующий символ во входном потоке не является пробельным и прекращает свою работу.

К концу первой итерации имеем следующий расклад:
`array[1] == x == 1`,
`printf` выводит `Times: 1`,
во входном потоке находится последовательность символов `2\n`.

*Вторая итерация* (последняя, `al == 2`). Во входном потоке уже есть последовательность символов `2\n`. Функция `scanf_s` помещает число `2` в переменную `x`, считывает символ новой строки `\n` и ожидает дальнейшего ввода. Вы снова добавляете во входной поток символы `2\n`; функция видит, что следующий символ — не пробельный, и прекращает свою работу.

К концу второй итерации расклад таков:
`array[2] == x == 2`,
`printf` выводит `Times: 2`,
во входном потоке так и остались необработанными символы `2\n`.

Окончательно, массив `array` заполнен следующими значениями:

```
array[3] == {1, 1, 2}
```

Как верно указали в комментариях и других ответах, если убрать директиву `"\n"`, то функция `scanf_s` перестанет "съедать" символы новой строки и при нажатии Enter она будет заканчивать свою работу.